# java.lang.RuntimeException: caused while executing doInBackground() in Xiaomi device only

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, xiaomi

Google play store is showing crash (I am not able to reproduce) in Xiaomi devices only. Please find crash logs below.
I had tried to reproduce this crash in Xiaomi device as well but not able to reproduce.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:309)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:234)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: 
>         at in.betterbutter.android.emoji.EmojiParse$ParseAsync.doInBackground
>   (EmojiParse.java:30)
>         at in.betterbutter.android.emoji.EmojiParse$ParseAsync.doInBackground
>   (EmojiParse.java:19)
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:295)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)

Here is my code:

```
public class EmojiParse {

    public void parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        new ParseAsync().execute(jsonObject);
    }

    public class ParseAsync extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = params[0];
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("emojis");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String text = object.getString("text");
                    String code = object.getString("code");
                    String surrogates = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(object.getString("surrogates"));


                    EmojiMap emojiMap = new EmojiMap();


                    emojiMap.hashSet.add(code);
                    emojiMap.displayMap.put(text, surrogates);
                    emojiMap.reverseMap.put(surrogates, text);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In xiaomi phones run in background is restricted for enabling it

`Setting` -> '`Apps' ->`installed Apps`-> 'Your App` -> `Background Restrictions` -> `No Restriction`

This is because xiaomi uses Baterry Optimisation  defaultly for every Application.

Check this link [here for example](http://nine-faq.9folders.com/articles/8771-how-to-turn-off-background-restriction-on-the-xiaomi-devices)

Use the given code to move to settings page

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

To remove restrictions.

Comment: can we do this programmably??

Comment: I fear we cant. Its is the feature of their customistion in MUI versions. try the above whether it is the problem.

Comment: Hi ,I am not able to reproduce this crash , provided that I am testing on Xiaomi device

Comment: I guess it is not a problem

Comment: @user8266276 that is optimisation is the problem if you cant reproduce the crash.

Comment: Hi Tomin , I do not think it is a solution as I had put restriction on, still I am not getting crash

Comment: @user8266276 : then it may be some intialisation error

Comment: can you help with solution